# Preventing ChromeOS from blanking the screen when working on a different tty

Tags: power-management, chroot, daemon, system-programming, ipc

I am running Archlinux in a chroot alongside Chrome OS on a chromebook. The original project is [there](https://github.com/guillaumebrunerie/Chromiarch-OS), my fork of it is [here](https://github.com/agravier/Chromiarch-OS) (mostly similar).

The issue is that the display power management of Chrome OS only takes touchpad and keyboard input made in Chrome OS's X on tty1 into account to reset the screen blanking countdown. So, if I am working in my chroot, on tty3 (console) or on tty4 (Arch's own X server), the backlight turns off after 5 minutes, whether I am idle or active. I have to then come back to tty1 to register some input there and get powerd to reactivate the backlight.

I don't want to deactivate powerd in Chrome OS, neither do I want to lengthen the default timeouts (which is what the original author or the chroot setup scripts did). I just want the screen backlight to turn off after a few minutes of inactivity, and to remain on when I am active in the chroot environment or in Chrome OS. Moreover, I want to minimally modify Chrome OS, as it's updated quite often and I want to keep the chroot reinstall script simple.

So, my idea is that I will program a couple of daemons. Daemon A runs in the chroot and detects whether I make keyboard or mouse inputs in Arch. Daemon C runs in chrome OS, checks the output of daemon A and does whatever is most appropriate to reset the screen blanking and power saving counters.

However, if user activity in the chroot can be figured out reading some /dev node, daemon A would not be necessary. **Can the age of the last user activity in the chroot (on /dev/tty3 and /dev/tty4) be somehow deduced from reading some /dev file, or by any other way from *without* the chroot?**

Secondly, commands such as `setterm -blank poke` seem to work from within the chroot, so daemon C may not be necessary if daemon A can alone reset the screen blanking countdown.  Hence, the second question: **Can the age of last user activity in the chroot (on /dev/tty3 and /dev/tty4) be somehow deduced from reading some /dev file, or by any other way from *within* the chroot?**

If you think that resetting the counters requires daemon A and C to both exist and communicate: **How is modern IPC done in GNU/Linux in practice? System V? POSIX? /proc files read and write? What would best work in my case?**

Finally, **do you know something else than `setterm -blank poke`, that the watchdog program should use to keep the backlight alive?**

Sorry for the long question, I hope you didn't have to read it all :)

Answer (score 2):

Just some pointers on how to (possibly) talk with the power daemon.

Have a look into the [Chromium OS](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os) [sources](http://git.chromium.org/) (no idea on how much this differs from Chrome OS), there you'll find [the `power_manager`s sources](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromiumos/platform/power_manager.git;a=tree) which might be helpful:

`README` explains what one can find there, among others:

> - `powerd` (`powerd.cc`)
>     Upper power manager. Adjusts device status based on whether the
>     user is idle and on **video activity indicator from the window manager**.
>     This daemon is responsible for dimming the backlight or turning off the
>     screen based on user idle, and it is responsible for adjusting backlight
>     intensity based on user input and ambient light condition. The daemon also
>     monitors plug state (on ac or on battery) and battery state-of-charge.
> - `xidle-example` (`examples/xidle_example.cc`)
>     Prints console notifications when the user is and is not idle.

So maybe you could interfere via `XIdle`, [`xidle_example.cc`](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromiumos/platform/power_manager.git;a=blob;f=examples/xidle_example.cc;h=b977ebb1c51d8908a20ed17d6d75cad8e562a966;hb=HEAD) could be helpful.

Another thing that might be useful is that [`RootPowerManager.conf`](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromiumos/platform/power_manager.git;a=blob;f=RootPowerManager.conf;h=775c6eb07e435e92cdb5239868160793f852abfa;hb=HEAD) tells you which [D-Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) address it listens on, `org.chromium.RootPowerManager`...maybe you can poke around there and find something, I haven't found any interface specs (but D-Bus should be able to tell you).

([`grep idle`](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromiumos%2Fplatform%2Fpower_manager.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=idle) might be helpful, too, it made me look at [`activity_detector_interface.h`](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromiumos/platform/power_manager.git;a=blob;f=activity_detector_interface.h;h=0e40dadfb0616b21c830af5e523353e2989be422;hb=HEAD), if this was D-Bus-exported, you could use it, i.e., disable Chrome OS's activity detection when your Arch system detects activity etc.)

Comment: Thank you, I thought that Chrome OS' power daemon would be blind and deaf, but thanks to your findings, I will now try the less hackish method of actually talking to it :)